# How to translate "thread" to Chinese？

Tags: translation

I found this word in [Github guide](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#notifications), and I don't know how to translate it to Chinese.It is used in this context:

> Muted **threads** won’t show up as unread again until you are specifically @mentioned again. This makes muting a great strategy for **threads** that you have little interest in (perhaps a sub-system that you aren’t familiar with). If you mark an issue as read, it will stay that way until someone comments on the **thread** again.

Comment: 主题 or 帖子. For example, your question here is a thread and the answers are posts. Posts are 跟帖.

Answer (score 1):

楼主： OP

沙发: first answerer

二楼: second answerer

三楼: third answerer

在这个部分,我们邀请每个人用英语来回答和沟通. Here we have ‘thread' as 部分

Answer (score 1):

In computer science we call thread "线程".

"程" stands for the way and "序" stands for order. So "程序" means program."线程" takes "程" from "程序".
"线" means line or "thread".

Answer (score 0):

In this article, thread should be translated into "message", which is "消息" in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

In the given context, you will subscribe to a thread and receive notifications of new comments. A thread = Github issue/project + its comments.

I think thread can be "话题" and new comment can be "新回应".